# Converting a csv with header and value in same segment

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV type file that has the header and value in the same segment like so:

```
"field1=value1", "field2=value2", etc
```

Is there a way to pull the fields to a header and the values as rows beneath?
I currently have:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='=')
df.to_csv(file + ".csv", index=None)
```

The output to the above is:

```
field1=value1, field2 value2, etc
```

The output I desire:

```
field1, field2, etc
value1, value2, etc
value, value, etc
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Ekalby and welcome to StackOverflow. What you try to achieve is not very clear: you could clarify by adding few lines of your csv and rephrase a bit what you want. And also what you tried.

Comment: I think you have to preprocess this with python and then build a dataframe. Is this a well-known format? There may be a module out there that already parses it. If not, what are its syntax rules? If quotes delimit the field, an equal sign the name, and if neither of those can be internal to the cell, a regex would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
import csv

data = []
fieldnames = set()

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        d_row = {}
        
        for entry in row:
            if entry:     # skip empty entries
                key, value = entry.split('=')
                d_row[key] = value
                fieldnames.add(key)
        
        data.append(d_row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(fieldnames))
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(data)
```

or to create a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=sorted(fieldnames))
print(df)
```

This reads each row using a standard `csv.reader()` and then splits each field into key value pairs and stored into a row dictionary which are then added to `data`. A set is used to learn all the fieldnames being used.

So if your input CSV file is:

```
"field1=value1","field2=value2"
"field1=value3","field2=value4"
```

The `output.csv` file would be:

```
field1,field2
value1,value2
value3,value4
```

Comment: I am getting a 'not enough values to unpack'. Later in the line, there is an empty segment, would an if solve this?

Comment: Can you show me the CSV file you are testing with it?  It probably means some entries in the row do not have `=` in them.

Comment: Not exactly.
The first row is:
"field1=value1", "field2=value2", etc, "field#=""value#""", "","",etc

Comment: Do all non-empty entries have `=` ?   I have updated it to skip over blank entries